# A better method to prove that $97 \mid 2^{48}-1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Proving that a given numbers is divisible by an other number is often simple but when it comes to big numbers i don’t know how to deal with them.

> Prove that $97 \mid 2^{48}-1$.

**My Attempt:**

$$2^{12} \equiv 22 \mod 97 \iff (2^{12})^{4} \equiv 22^4\equiv1 \mod 97$$
$$\iff 2^{48} \equiv 1 \mod 97 \iff 97 \mid 2^{48}-1 $$

It seems short but the problem here is that $2^{48} \equiv 1 \mod 97$ Should be proven, but i’ve just used a calculator to prove it, So is there a better method to prove thi type of problem.

Comment: Iterated squaring works well.  $2^8=256\equiv 62\pmod {97}$ and so on.

Comment: What you've done here is totally legitimate; there are reasons _why_ $97|2^{48}-1$ (see [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) and the [quadratic reciprocity condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) ), but you don't need to know 'why' to show that it's true.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki these are some advanced topics for me .

Comment: $2=14'^2\pmod{97}$ so $2^{48}=14^{96}\pmod{97}$ and that is $1$ by Fermat's Little Theorem

Comment: See *modular order reduction* in the linked dupe for the general idea, and see the many posts linked there for examples. In particular [this linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24181/242) works here since $\,2\equiv 14^2\ \ $

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022593/proving-that-89-mid-244-1) is a related question